# Google FHIR API - Patient $everything

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to use this api . https://healthcare.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/REGION/datasets/DATASET_ID/fhirStores/FHIR_STORE_ID/fhir/Patient/PATIENT_ID/$everything

I am getting this error

```
{
  "issue": [
    {
      "code": "not-supported",
      "details": {
        "text": "bad_resource_type"
      },
      "diagnostics": "unsupported resource type",
      "severity": "error"
    }
  ],
  "resourceType": "OperationOutcome"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct command according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/healthcare/docs/how-tos/fhir-resources#getting_all_patient_compartment_resources) should be:

```
curl -X GET \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth print-access-token) \
     "https://healthcare.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/REGION/datasets/DATASET_ID/fhirStores/FHIR_STORE_ID/fhir/Patient/PATIENT_ID/\$everything"
```

Notice that a `"\"` sign is missing before the `$everything"`.

Comment: Thanks! . I have tried with this https://healthcare.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/{{ project_name  }}/locations/{{ region  }}/datasets/{{ dataset_name  }}/fhirStores/fhir-store/fhir/Patient/0a1e63cf-27c0-4f15-81bf-628582cb936a/\$everything.   Same error :  {
  "issue": [
    {
      "code": "not-supported",
      "details": {
        "text": "bad_resource_type"
      },
      "diagnostics": "unsupported resource type",
      "severity": "error"
    }
  ],
  "resourceType": "OperationOutcome"
}

Comment: I still see an issue on the URL. Notice that a `/` character is missing between `projects` and `{{project_name}}`. The correct URL should be: `https://healthcare.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/{{project_name}}/locations/{{region}}/datasets/{{dataset_name}}/fhirStores/fhir-store/fhir/Patient/{{patient_id}}/\$everything`. Also you need to make sure that the Patient resource has some resources associated (like an Encounter or an Observation). Follow [this](https://cloud.google.com/healthcare/docs/how-tos/fhir-resources#creating_a_fhir_resource) in order to understand how to create resources.

Comment: Hi, Sorry I put the url wrong here , https://healthcare.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects//{{ project_name  }}/locations/{{ region  }}/datasets/{{ dataset_name  }}/fhirStores/fhir-store/fhir/Patient/988e6160-90e7-4f73-b049-27e69cc7fede/\$everything .  I have created one Observation and Encounter resource. Other search queries are working. e.g .  https://healthcare.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects//{{ project_name  }}/locations/{{ region  }}/datasets/{{ dataset_name  }}/fhirStores/fhir-store/fhir/Observation?subject=Patient/988e6160-90e7-4f73-b049-27e69cc7fede

Comment: , https://healthcare.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects//{{ project_name  }}/locations/{{ region  }}/datasets/{{ dataset_name  }}/fhirStores/fhir-store/fhir/Encounter?subject=Patient/988e6160-90e7-4f73-b049-27e69cc7fede ,  https://healthcare.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects//{{ project_name  }}/locations/{{ region  }}/datasets/{{ dataset_name  }}/fhirStores/fhir-store/fhir/Patient/988e6160-90e7-4f73-b049-27e69cc7fede .   Only  "$everything" API is not working .

Comment: Please edit your post to include the exact way you are creating and getting the FHIR resources. After following [this](https://cloud.google.com/healthcare/docs/how-tos/fhir-resources#creating_a_fhir_resource) to create first a Patient, then an Encounter and finally an Observation resource and afterwards [this](https://cloud.google.com/healthcare/docs/how-tos/fhir-resources#healthcare-get-patient-everything-cli-curl) to get all the compartment resources I was able get all the resources.